# Explain the jQuery code: $('.maxlength').after("<span></span>").next().hide().end().keypress

Tags: jquery

Here is my code.. but I am unable to understand this code.

```
$('.maxlength')

    .after("<span></span>")

    .next()

    .hide()

    .end()

    .keypress(function(e) {

        var current = $(this).val().length;

        if (current >= 130) {

            if (e.which != 0 && e.which != 8) {

                e.preventDefault();

            }

        }

        $(this).next().show().text(130 - current);

    });
```

Comment: It is, by the way, an horrible way to accomplish this. Don't use this code!

Comment: @paxdiablo : my code means not written by mee.. if i know this how can i ask for help.. if possible make help dont do comments.. sorry and thank you

Comment: i agree with you , lot of times we work on code already developed by others...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.maxlength') // select all items with class 'maxlength'

.after("<span></span>") // insert a span after 

.next() // move to the span

.hide() // hide the span

.end() // go back to originally selected element

.keypress(function(e) { // add a keypress event handler function

    var current = $(this).val().length; // get the length of the input value (a string)

    if (current >= 130) { //if it's long

        if (e.which != 0 && e.which != 8) { // and if certain keys weren't pressed (delete?)

            e.preventDefault(); // don't do what those keys would normally do - i.e. ignore the keypress

        }

    }

    $(this).next().show().text(130 - current); // show the remaining chars in the newly added span

});
```

...so basically this code makes a text area have a character limit of 130 characters and shows you how many more you're allowed to type.

Comment: so much thanks brother.. so here end() means stop the current element and go to its previous right! when ever we use end() is it go to previous one or the original one?

Comment: @Mihir: http://api.jquery.com/end/ : *End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.*